# Ability to merge lists for subscribed tags

Tags: feature-request, subscription

I want to get notified for some related tags. It could be better if I have an option to merge the results of all related tags in one email. This could be useful to get rid of duplicated items as well.

Comment: You could also create a new filter that includes all the tags you want and subscribe to it - https://stackexchange.com/filters/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I guess this will met my need.